# How to load a other ios apps in keychain data?

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain

Currently, I made a two application in iOS Apps.

this is my source code.

---

**TestProject Source code ** -->write to keychain

```
KeychainItemWrapper *idKeyChain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"TestProject" accessGroup:@"TestProject.com.test"];

[idKeyChain.keychainItemData setObject:@"testValue" forKey:(id)kSecValueData];

[idKeyChain release];
```

---

**TestKeyChain Source code** -->load to keychain

```
KeychainItemWrapper *idKeyChain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"TestProject" accessGroup:@"TestProject.com.test"];

NSString *username = [idKeyChain objectForKey:kSecAttrAccount];

[idKeyChain release];

NSLog(@"password : %@", username);
```

---

I guessed to print screen what username value.
`<password : testValue>`

But Log's print..
`<password : >`

Currently, I wasted three hours only this problem..
what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your setting code should look something like this:

```
keychainItemWrapper = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:KEYCHAIN_ID accessGroup:nil];
[keychainItemWrapper setObject:username forKey:kSecAttrAccount];
[keychainItemWrapper setObject:password forKey:kSecValueData];
```

Your getting code should look something like this:

```
keychainItemWrapper = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:KEYCHAIN_ID accessGroup:nil];
NSString *username = [keychainItemWrapper objectForKey:kSecAttrAccount];
NSString *password = [keychainItemWrapper objectForKey:kSecValueData];
```

Add the appropriate access group string if you want to share the keychain data between apps per Apple docs.

Good luck!